# Columns aren't being returned from api query

Tags: soap-api, php

I'm using the php SF api with the soap client. I've had a script running that pulls in some info from our SF database and does some stuff with it on our local database.

Before, this was the query I was using to grab the data from SF:

```
$query = "SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, Product__c from Account WHERE Type LIKE 'Customer%'";
```

Recently, some new custom fields have been added, so I modified the query to include them:

```
$query = "SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, CMM__c, Product__c, DCM_Lookup__c, ADCM__c, DAM__c from Account WHERE Type LIKE 'Customer%'";
```

However, the new fields aren't being returned. When I run this:

```
    $response = $this->mySforceConnection->query($query);   
    $queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
    foreach ($queryResult->records as $record) {
       print_r($record);
    }
```

All I get are the original fields being returned:

```
stdClass Object
(
[Id] => SomeClientId
[Name] => SomeClientName
[OwnerId] => SomeOwnerId
[Product__c] => SomeProduct
)
```

With the new ones not showing up. Just to check, I tried pulling this content with SalesForce's Apex data loader and the fields show up there. Also, I'm not getting any errors while running the code. I also updated the wsdl file, which hasn't seemed to do anything. Not really sure what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course as soon as I post this, I answer the question. Apparently, for some reason, my script was referencing the old wsdl file. This I find very confusing since I updated the file. However, once I named it a different name, in both the script and on my server, everything works as it should.